# How to troubleshoot networking problems

Tags: networking

I am seeing a problem with few IP Cameras as I am loosing connections with the cameras from the server. The connection loss happens after running for few months. I don't loose the connection with all the cameras.

Please provide pointers on how to trouble shoot this problem.

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: Not programming-related - belongs on serverfault

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark, to analyse what happens when you lose the connection

Comment: It uses RTSP (Real Time Streaming Protocol) protocol. Does wireshark help for this as well?